# What is the lowest temperture I can use to cook fresh pasta?

Tags: temperature, food-science, pasta

Say I want to cook fresh pasta and I don't have access to a stove or hotplate.  I can heat water with an immersion circulator.  I can get close, but can't achieve a boil.  What is the lowest temperature needed to cook fresh (water and/or egg based...but not dried) pasta?  While I provide the circulator as an example, this is less of a modernist technique question and more of a science of cooking pasta question.

Comment: see: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/91685/is-it-possible-to-cook-pasta-at-room-temperature-with-low-enough-pressure/91730#91730

Comment: I wonder if 140 F would apply here for food safety?

Comment: Thanks @Jolenealaska. There is one response in that discussion addressing fresh, which references a paper examining polymerization of gluten in dried pasta.  While the abstract (all I have access to) mentions that the researchers studied protein polymerization first using fresh pasta, and provides a temperature range of 60 - 68C for two reactions, it is mainly a paper about dried pasta.  So, for me the questions then becomes does protein polymerization = "cooked" as we would experience it in a finished dish?

Comment: @Paparazzi so far, it sounds like temps at or above 140F (60C) are necessary anyway.

Comment: In [the highest village in Italy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trepalle) water boils at around 92C [Wikipedia - high altitude cooking, 2000m](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-altitude_cooking). They can probably eat decent pasta. Can your circulator do that?

Comment: @ChrisH, yes it can.  But...how low can one go?  Your comment also adds the additional physical phenomenon of boiling to the situation.  I don't think a boil is necessary (regardless of temp), but will stand corrected if that is incorrect.

Comment: The boil shouldn't do anything (except possibly affect convective mixing). I think you might end up doing an experiment - to me that's the point of circulators (though the one I repaired recently had a max setpoint of 100C). But I thought the effect of altitude led to an interesting bit of context.

Comment: @ChrisH sell that method of preparation to hipsters as ancient mountain pasta before some other yahoo does it :)

Comment: @rackandboneman Nice idea, but you can have that one -- my file of daft hipster business plans is getting rather full and I still don't want the compulsory beard.

Comment: Not related to temperature, but as I understand it pasta needs to be *in* the water to cook properly.  I don't know about you, but I would *definitely not* put pasta directly in the water my immersion circulator is circulating.  That just sounds like a recipe for getting things all kinds of gummed up. That said, I suspect there are all kinds of interesting things you could do with sealing the fresh pasta in an bag *with* the sauce...

Comment: @senschen I have not had a chance to test this yet, but my thought was to place a bag of water in the bath, then put the fresh pasta in the bag of heated water.  That way the circulator would only be in the heating water, not the pasta water.

Comment: @moscafj  That would probably work.  Since there wasn't anything like that in your question, I thought I'd drop a note.  I just got my own immersion circulator, so I was intrigued by the question, but with that one big caveat. :)  If you do try it, you should post an answer and let us know how it works out.

Comment: I have cooked dried shell pasta in an electric filter coffee machine before. It took a while but it worked. I am not sure what water temperature that had, probably high 80s C.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and pick up a camping stove, they are only around $20 and use disposable butane. They are brilliant if you don't have access to a full stove.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cooking pasta at a full rolling boil (100°C at sea level or less at higher altitudes) is just conventional, it is not the boiling the cooks pasta but the temperature:

pasta cooking is influenced by three factors: water penetration inside the pasta, **gelatinization of the starch** (it normally occurs at a temperature between **60°C and 70°C** for wheat starch) and the **denaturation and consequent coagulation of gluten (at 70°C-80°C)**.
A temperature above 80°C for a certain time (slightly longer than what you'd need at 100°C to compensate for the slower penetration of water into the pasta) should guarantee a perfectly cooked pasta.

This is the same for dried pasta and for fresh pasta; fresh will cook in less time, and you should probably taste it during the cooking process to find the right texture.

The rolling boil helps to keep the pasta well separated and to avoid sticking, but a water circulator would probably take care of that too

Comment: source: http://bressanini-lescienze.blogautore.espresso.repubblica.it/2017/02/07/la-cottura-della-pasta/ (in italian)

Comment: If you can [edit] your answer to add the source it would be better

Answer (score 2):

From [Ask the Food Lab: Can I Start Pasta In Cold Water?](http://www.seriouseats.com/2013/05/ask-the-food-lab-can-i-start-pasta-in-cold-water.html)

> Even if it loses its boil, the pasta will still continue to cook so long as it's kept above 180°F/80°C or so.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question -- they're talking about dried pasta.  With fresh pasta, you need to gelatinize the outside of the pasta quickly, so it doesn't turn into paste.